# How to query "Multipicklist" type on Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, salesforce, psycopg2

I am working on Heroku Connect (integrated with Salesforce). One of my columns has the type of "Multipicklist".

I am working in Python, so using psycopg2.

What is the correct way for querying, matching a single variable value in a multipicklist type column?

An example is:

Say `custom__c` has column called `multipicklistcol__c`.
I have some `custom__c` row with `multipicklistcol__c` values of `{'A','B','C'}`.

If I have a variable `param = 'A'`, how do I select my `custom__c` row using `param`?

I have tried a few different approaches, none of which work for me:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT name, sfid FROM salesforce.custom__c WHERE (%s) <@ multipicklistcol__c;""", (param, ))

cur.execute("""SELECT name, sfid FROM salesforce.custom__c WHERE (%s) IN multipicklistcol__c;""", (param, ))

cur.execute("""SELECT name, sfid FROM salesforce.custom__c WHERE multipicklistcol__c includes (%s);""", (param, ))

cur.execute("""SELECT name, sfid FROM salesforce.custom__c WHERE (%s) = ANY(multipicklistcol__c)""", (param, ))
```

Comment: Can you show how the column is defined in the table? According to [this](https://learn.capstorm.com/copystorm-menu/storm-frequently-asked-questions/item/165-copystorm-faq-datatype-mapping) MULTIPICKLIST should be represented as VARCHAR in the database, but in your example it looks more like an array

Comment: I actually saw that resource, thanks! On Heroku, the type is explicitly defined as "multipicklist", but this might be to play nice with Salesforce. Selecting the column unconditionally yielded some interesting results: iterating over the data and printing the values  (`for x in data: print x`) acted like iterating over characters in a string. But it actually returned a tuple object, which I learned trying to manipulate it. So my related question: how do you query the like above knowing the `multipicklist` is treated as a tuple?

Comment: And the final example I tried above (with `ANY()`) explicitly said it was invalid because the `multipicklist` is not an array.

Comment: There is no postgresql inbuilt column type called 'MULTIPICKLIST'. Although it is possible to define custom types, I'd say it is unlikely that is the case. Try connecting to the database using psql (postgresql SQL CLI) and use command `\d salesforce.custom__c` to see how the table is defined. Add that output to the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own typecaster. See the docs about [type casting](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-of-sql-types-into-python-objects). Maybe you can get away with just creating a new [array type caster](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.new_array_type) on a base type already handled.